# Python calling a function with the same name as named argument

Tags: python, function, scope, global-variables, local-variables

In a module, I have two functions, let's call them `f` and `g`.  `g` takes a named argument `f`.  I'd like to call `f` from inside `g`.  How do I access the function `f`?  Unfortunately, due to compatibility issues, I can't change their names.

**Edit**

To clarify, this is what I mean:

```
def f():
  ... code ...

def g(f=1):
  ... code ...
  x = f() # error, f doesn't name the function anymore
  ... code ...
```

Comment: You've got a couple of answers - it'd be good for reference if you could provide some example code to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though `globals()` seems like a simple solution here, you can also achieve the same thing by defining a inner function inside `g()` that calls the global `f`:

```
def f():print "hello"

def g(f):
    def call_global_f():
        global f
        f()
    call_global_f()      #calls the global f
    print f              #prints the local f

g('foo')
```

**output:**

```
hello
foo
```

Answer (score 7):

You could add a new name for the function.

E.g:

```
def f():
    pass

f_alt = f

def g(f=3):
    f_alt()
```

Just don't export f_alt from the module.

Comment: It could also be a default argument: `def g(f=3, f_alt=f)`.

Comment: That confines the scope and is more elegant, @eryksun.  Nice.

Comment: Though I'm not pleased with the option of `g(4, 6) # fail hard`.  That is to say — this is not what function parameters are for, and it points out Python's need for a more flexible approach to variable scopes.

Comment: Not that it necessarily helps here, but the 'fail hard' scenario is addressed in Python 3 by keyword-only arguments. The signature changes to `def g(f=3, *, f_alt=f)`.

Answer (score 6):

Basic example using `globals`:

```
def f():
    print 'f'

def g(name):
    globals()[name]()

g('f')
```